# How to loop into all webapplications, sitecollections, sites and print all permission groups and users

Tags: 2007, stsadm

I am using sharepoint 2007 and is installed on windows server 2003 R2. I would like to create some script to show a environment summary like:

```
webapplications
 site collections
  websites
   usergroups
    roles
    users
```

I can access stsadm. I hope I can write the summary to some file. Otherwise print it on the screen. How can I implement this?

ps. isn't it possible to use/install powershell on windows server 2003 r2?

Comment: yes powershell can be installed...then perform two steps :        1) Set the  Execution Policy to 'RemoteSigned'                                                                 2) load the SharePoint assemblies

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2007 does not have PowerShell support.

In Visual Studio create a console application that loops through all the site collections and sites. You need to run this program on the SharePoint 2007 server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462161(v=office.14).aspx

```
static void Main(string[] args)
      {
                  SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
                 //Get all SharePoint Web services
                  SPWebService service = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>("");

                  foreach (SPWebApplication webapp in service.WebApplications)
                  {
                       Console.WriteLine(webapp.Name);
                      //Enumerate through each site collection
                      foreach (SPSite site in webapp.Sites)
                      { 
                          //Console.WriteLine(site.Url);

                          //Enumerate through each sub-site
                          foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                          { 
                              ...
```

For every site print the users and security settings. 
You will find plenty of samples online.

**Note:** This can be a lengthy and resource intensive operation. Make sure you Dispose() all your objects properly.

Comment: I knwo it is possible to do this stuff programmatically. But I would like to avoid development. Is there some solution in stsadm?

Comment: Maybe Garry lapointe stsadm extensionhttp://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/

Comment: Or the tool 'Sushi' has a "security audit" reporting function http://sushi.codeplex.com/releases/view/22248.